# Unaccent extension of Postgresql 9.1 returning empty row

Tags: sql, postgresql, unaccent

I created the extension "unaccent" on the postgresql database but when I run a select using the "unaccent" it always return 1 row but with a blank line.

```
select ts_lexize('unaccent', 'Hôtel');
ts_lexize
-----------

(1 row)
```

Expected according to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html):

```
select ts_lexize('unaccent','Hôtel');
ts_lexize
-----------
{Hotel}
(1 row)
```

Also when I run:

```
SELECT unaccent('unaccent', 'Hôtel');
```

it shows:

```
unaccent
----------
Hôtel
(1 row)
```

Comment: I suppose you have the `.rules` file installed, right?

Comment: Yes, it's the default Ubuntu installation, it's located on /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/tsearch_data/unaccent.rules. If I change the dictionary 'unaccent' to another one, it says that the dict doens't exists, so it is using the right dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I was just checking the obvious, first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that the problem was that the database encoding, which was using the `SQL_ASCII` encoding, so I dropped the database, recreated it with `UTF-8` and then it started to worked fine. It seems that the `unaccent` doesn't work with `SQL_ASCII`.

Comment: Whoa... " It seems that the unaccent doesn't work with SQL_ASCII" is quite an statement..  i'm searching in the official docs of postgres and there is no clue about that..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Postgres editor or Operational System.
Problably you're using MacOS or Linux to show the results. I agreed Tarantula. If you change encoding database to UTF-8, it will be much better.

Try to execute this select in a Postgres Windows editor. With me worked. The "blank" result appered.

Hgs =)